# Best practice for handling positions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best practice for moving rows. So that you might want to change order of items. Now if you make a new column called order_id or something, wouldn't that fail if I delete or select rows.

Another method I guess is to just switch values completely with an primary ID, so just values except the ID are changed. however I do not know what people usually use. There are so many websites that give you the ability to change order of things.how so they do that?

Comment: They sort the result sets from the SQL queries (`order by`).

Comment: You use a weight column, give each item a weight when saving a new row and ordering your queries by the weight. When a row is removed, it creates a gap but that has no effect on the sorting. When moving a row to a specific weight, add +1 to all with equal or larger weights.

Answer (score -1):

Every SQL statement that returns a visible result set should include an ORDER BY clause so that the results are consistent.  The Standard does not guarantee that the order of rows in a particular table will remain constant or consistent, even if obvious changes aren't made to the table.

What you use for your ORDER BY clause depends on the use case.  A date value is the usual choice for a comment thread or blog entry ordering.  However, if you want the user to be able to customize the order that a result set shows in, then you have to provide a column that represents the position of the row, and adjust the value of that column when the user makes changes to the order they see.

For example, if you decide that the column will contain a sequential number, starting with 1 for the first row, 2 for the second, etc.  then you will be ok to delete rows when they need to be deleted without having to do updates.  However, if you insert a row, you will need to give the row you insert the sequential number appropriate for it's position, and update all rows below that with their new position.  Same goes for if you move a row from somewhere else to a new location;  the rows between the new and old locations need to be updated with new postion indexes.